# Validate password in php, with at least two uppercase, two lowercase and two numbers, in any order

Tags: php, regex

What I am trying to do is the following:

I am trying to validate a password, the password must have at least two uppercase, two lowercase, two numbers and minimum 8 characters.

For this I am trying to use a regular expression which is the following:

```
$uppercase = preg_match('#[A-Z]#', $password);
$lowercase = preg_match('#[a-z]#', $password);
$number = preg_match('#[0-9]#', $password);
$special = preg_match('#[#[W]{2,}#', $password); 
$length = strlen($password) >= 8;

if(!$uppercase || !$lowercase || !$number || !$special || !$length) {
  $errorpw = 'Bad Password';
```

But this only validates 1 number, 1 uppercase and 1 lowercase. The order in which these data are written can be any, it doesn't have to be a specific order like for example ASdf12, it can be mixed example AsDf12

Comment: `'#[A-Z]#'` => `'#[A-Z].*[A-Z]#'` / `'#[A-Z][^A-Z]*[A-Z]#'` and the rest should be changed in this way.

Comment: change to preg_match_all and you will get a count of occurances of that regex